# Laravel query scope with multiple where clauses returns incorrect data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have below table `consols`:

```php
Schema::create('consols', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->double('current_weight', 8, 3)->default(0);
    $table->double('current_weight', 8, 3)->default(0);
    $table->double('final_weight', 8, 3)->default(0);
    $table->double('final_cbm', 8, 3)->default(0);    
    $table->timestamp('finals_sent', 0)->nullable();
});
```

Which contain an entry like below:

```sql
id | current_weight | current_cbm | final_weight | final_cbm | finals_sent         |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
1  | 45.000         | 1.000       | 200.000      | 10.000    | 2019-09-26 10:03:59 |
```

I have written a scope on my model `Consol`, to filter the entries, where: `finals_sent` is not null, `current_weight > final_weight` OR `current_cbm > final_cbm`:

```php
public function scopeOfCurrentGreaterThanFinals($query)
{
    return $query->whereNotNull('finals_sent')->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('current_weight', '>', 'final_weight')
            ->orWhere('current_cbm', '>', 'final_cbm');
    });

}
```

When I use it and dump it out - I am expecting to see **no** results:

```
$consols = Consol::ofCurrentGreaterThanFinals()
           ->orderBy('awb', 'DESC')
           ->get()
           ->toArray();
```

However, the entry above is still being shown:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:24 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "current_weight" => 45.0
    "current_cbm" => 1.0
    "final_weight" => 200.0
    "final_cbm" => 10.0
    "finals_sent" => "2019-09-26 10:03:59"
  ]
]
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? I think I cleary states that I only want to see the results, where:

- current_weight > final_weight **or**
- current_cbm > current_weight **and**
- finals_sent is not null

And above entry does not fit this, because the current_weight and current_cbm is clearly not higher than the final_weight and final_cbm.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what about your offWeek scope the Finals scope seems fine

Comment: Removed that from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ok, here is the issue. In order to compare the two columns you have to use `whereRaw()` as `where` for the second parameter expects a value, not a column.
So this should work, I tested with your database and values.

```
return $query->whereNotNull('finals_sent')->where(function ($q) {
            $q->whereRaw('current_weight > final_weight')
                ->orWhereRaw('current_cbm > final_cbm');
        });
```

Comment: I just updated the question. I actually did intend to get the results if `current_weight` or `current_cbm` is higher than their `final_` counterparts. However, it still shouldn't return any results.

Comment: @oliverbj Updated my answer. Hope this works now. Sorry for the small misunderstanding.